# flash as3 trying to play audio from external swf and getting message "Call to a possibly undefined method"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm able to load graphics from an external library with no problems, but for some reason all of the audio will not load/play.

Here's the loader class I'm using...

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.Font;

    public class LoadLibrary extends MovieClip
    {
        private var gear:MovieClip = new mcGear();
        private var txtLoading:BlankClip;

        private var _gameLib:String = "";

        private var _Impact:Font = new Impact();

        public function LoadLibrary(gameLibrary:String) 
        {
            _gameLib = gameLibrary;

            addChild(gear);
            gear.x = 512;
            gear.y = 384;
            gear.alpha = .2;
            gear.scaleX = .33;
            gear.scaleY = .33;

            txtLoading = new BlankClip(_Impact, "LOADING...", -400, -60, 800, 120, 26, "center", 5);
            addChild(txtLoading);
            txtLoading.x = 512;
            txtLoading.y = 525;
            txtLoading.alpha = .2;                      

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_gameLib);          
            LoadVars.LIBLOADER.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gameLibraryLoaded);
            LoadVars.LIBLOADER.load(request);               
        }

        private function gameLibraryLoaded(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeChild(gear);
            removeChild(txtLoading);

            LoadVars.LIBLOADER.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gameLibraryLoaded);

            var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.currentTarget);
            LoadVars.APPDOMAIN = loaderInfo.applicationDomain;

            dispatchEvent(new GameEvents(GameEvents.LIBRARY_LOADED));
        }

    }

}
```

and the functions in my main class...

```
private function loadLib():void 
{
    _loadGraphics = new LoadLibrary("Elemental_Library.swf");
    addChild(_loadGraphics);        

    _loadGraphics.addEventListener(GameEvents.LIBRARY_LOADED, test);
}       

private function test(e:GameEvents):void 
{
    trace("LOADED");

    var music:Sound = new GameMusic();
    music.play();           
}
```

Everything works fine until I try music.play and I get "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method GameMusic." I've tried several other audio clips and I get the same message. I tried creating a new library and imported just one audio file, same message. I verified I'm using the correct linkage names and the crazy part is that all of the movie clips load just fine from the same library.

Comment: Do you have the sound exporting for Actionscript in the External_Library.fla?

Comment: which line gets the error?

Comment: Wow, I figured it out. A total ID10T error.

I forgot to tell it to load the music from the external swf. Changed test to...

 private function test(e:GameEvents):void 
 {
  trace("LOADED");
  
  var musicClass:Class = Class(LoadVars.APPDOMAIN.getDefinition("GameMusic"));
  var music:Sound = Sound(new musicClass());
  music.play();   
 }

I knew it was something stupid :P

Answer (score 0):

Changed test to...

```
private function test(e:GameEvents):void 
{ 
    trace("LOADED"); 
    var musicClass:Class = Class(LoadVars.APPDOMAIN.getDefinition("GameMusic")); 
    var music:Sound = Sound(new musicClass()); music.play();     
}
```

I knew it was something stupid :P